# Thymeleaf form with path variable

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a form with a method `get` and with an action. When I submit the form, the action parameter contains `id` as a standard parameter like `?id=1`. How do I pass this parameter as path variable?

```
<form method="get" th:action="@{/mycontroller/}">
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: can you use javascript? or does it have to be html-ish only?

Comment: Yes, but maybe is it possible to solve with thymeleaf.

Comment: I cant see a way with Thymeleaf, since it renders a static html page which is  sent down to the client. The `th:action="@{/mycontroller/}"` is rendered server side by Thymeleaf. There is no magic data binding between the action url and the input name="id" from Thymeleaf for the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **html:**

```
<form id="myForm" method="get" th:action="@{/mycontroller/}">
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

And then with **JQuery** you could do something like this:

```
var $form = $( '#myForm' );
var $idField = $( "#id" );

$form.submit( function( event ) {

  // respects th:action="@{/mycontroller/}" and appends id
  $form.attr( 'action',  $form.attr('action') + $idField.val() );

  // otherwise ?id=xx
  $idField.prop( "disabled", true );

  // submits the form in the normal way !
  return;
});
```